# prototype function which will check all other function return true or false

Tags: jquery, oop

```
function checkname(){return false;}

function checkemail(){return false;}

     //submit
    function submitFormFunction(event){
        //array validation function
        var validators = [checkname, checkemail];
        // bypass all function
        var valid = validators.reduce(function(valid, validator){
        return validator() && valid;
        }, true);

        if(valid){
        $("#othersubmit-result").html('');
        }else{
        $("#othersubmit-result").css('color', 'red');
        $("#othersubmit-result").html('sumbit not requirements.');
        }
        return valid;
    }
```

this is my scrip , my intention is to make a function which will validation all other form function , so lets say if checkname function return = true and checkemail function return = true also, the function submitFormFunction will check this 2 functions , if all = true , it will pass the function and submit the form else let them know they the form is not finish.

```
var ClassSignUpValidation = function (){};

ClassSignUpValidation.prototype.CheckName = function (_target)
{
return false;
}

ClassSignUpValidation.prototype.CheckEmail = function (_target)
{
return false;
}
```

but now i am using prototype js oop , this how my function looks like , how to do i make similar function like my old one and check all those function are they return true or false ?

error

```
ClassSignUpValidation.prototype.CheckName = function (_target)
{
  //set target id to jquery
  _target = "#" + _target;

  //set variable
  var username_target = $(_target);
  var username_value = username_target.val();
  var username_errorspan = $("#user-errorResult");

****//here is the error****
if (username_value.length >= 4){
   $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"/main/class/classvalidation.php",
    async:false,
    data:{
    "username": username_value
    },
    success: function(data)
    {
      var usernameAvailable = JSON.parse(data);
      var color = usernameAvailable.exists ? "#dfe0e6" : "red";
      username_errorspan.html(usernameAvailable.message);
      username_errorspan.css("color", color);
      username_target.css("border-color", color);
      if(usernameAvailable.exists === true){
        return true;
      }
    }
  });
};

return false;
}
```

error

```
if (username_value.length >= 4){ here is the error point in
```

Answer (score 0):

you can still use your code and instead of giving reference as function name use instance.functionname for ex.

```
submitFormFunction = function(event){
            //array validation function
            var validator = new ClassSignUpValidation
            var validators = [validator.checkname, validator.checkemail];
            // bypass all function
            var valid = validators.reduce(function(valid, validator){
            return validator() && valid;
            }, true);

            if(valid){
            $("#othersubmit-result").html('');
            }else{
            $("#othersubmit-result").css('color', 'red');
            $("#othersubmit-result").html('sumbit not requirements.');
            }
            return valid;
        }
```

this should work.

Comment: have a error :Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: are you passing necessary arguments etc. because the error about length is not from prototype or class, its from other code, so check your console for trace of error origination

Comment: i am not sure what's wrong on my code , please check i edit the error point, thank for helping.

Comment: check type of variable if its string or array then only you can access .length method use console.log(typeof username_value)